# Can I setup PostCSS Preset Env in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, configuration, postcss

I want to use [PostCSS Preset Env](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/tree/main/plugin-packs/postcss-preset-env) in my project. In the documentation it says I need to [write a config file](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/tree/main/plugin-packs/postcss-preset-env#quick-start). Is it possible to instead of writing a config file have the configuration in my `package.json`?

In this [other project](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-load-config#packagejson) it shows as this might be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried, and it works.

Example in `package.json`:

```json
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ],
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "postcss-preset-env": {
        "stage": 0
      }
    }
  }
```